# stationary point of multivariable function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I got this from a true false exam:

> "A stationary point of a function of 2 variable is ALWAYS either un local maximum, local minimum or a saddle point"

The answers to the above statement was on a True False exam and the correct answer was that that statement is false but I do not understand why.

I really have problems understanding the possibilities of the type of stationary point that are possible.

Can a stationary point of multivariable function in $\mathbb{R}^2$ be a point of discontinuity?

or is a stationary point of multivariable function $\mathbb{R}^2$ always one of the following three:
local max
local min
or saddle point
?

[image: I found this on khanAcademy but does it mean that a stationary point can be a point of discoutinuity?]

Comment: There is also something called a Monkey saddle, which is not really a saddle point: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_saddle

Comment: @Thomas: That is just a kind of saddle point! Isn't it? :)

Comment: Critical points are zeroes of the derivative, therefore continuity is always granted. I was thinking of $f (x,y)=x^3+y^3$.

Comment: What's your definition of saddle point? If I recall correctly, the one I know is "critical point which isn't an extremum". Using this definition, the statement is true.

Comment: @GitGud points where the function is non-differentiable is also termed as critical point but certainly they are not saddle points.